# Notification icon that looks like 2 arrows inside a circle with leaf on Huawei device

Tags: huawei, notification-icons

I have a Huawei Mate 9. The notification icon looks like this:

[image: Unknown notification icon]

> 2 arrows inside a circle with leaf

Things that I have done:

- Tried to find this on Google but returned no results
- Checked my apps icons, nothing matches

First, I thought it belonged to Snapseed, but it's not theirs.

Comment: Basically two arrows facing opposite to each other indicates **data** transfer on most of the phones and a leaf indicates **eco**. So it's a data saver basically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a notification originating from the Data Saver feature in Huawei ROMs (EMUI 5.0).

Data saver helps to reduce data usage by preventing background apps from sending or receiving data and limiting the data access frequency of running apps.

> When data saver is active, a data icon with a leaf will appear in the
>   status bar. This may prevent users from receiving updates from emails,
>   chat and other social media apps, and images will only be displayed
>   when you touch them. To enable the data saver mode, go to Settings ->
>   Mobile data -> Data saver.

[image]

Source: *[First view of EMUI 5.0 ROM: Android 7](https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/4109528/all)*

Comment: On my Honor view 20, it is "smart data saver"

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it means that Smart Data Saver is on. This prevents some apps to run in the background so you don't use a lot of data in case you are roaming in another country, for example.
Go to settings, wireless and networks, data usage, and click on smart data saver to turn on/off.
When turned on you can still select the apps you want to keep using data and give them permission.[image]